# Hive SQL, How do I check multiple previous rows for the same reference

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

I have a large dataset that contains a reference, asset, start and end dates.
I want to assign a key, starting at 1, for each asset by the reference, if the reference is the same and the start and end dates follow on from each other, then use the same key so I end up with:

```
Asset   Ref     Start       End         Key
A23BCD  12345   01/01/1900  01/01/2020  1
A23BCD  12345   02/01/2020  17/06/2020  1
A23BCD  67890   01/09/2020  31/10/2020  2
A23BCD  77777   01/11/2020  31/12/9999  3
```

I am using data in Hadoop, and using HiveQL to assign the key, but this only checks the previous 5 rows:

```
create table temp_user.a1                              
row format delimited fields terminated by '\001'                                                               
stored as orc tblproperties("ORC.COMPRESS"="SNAPPY","ORC.COMPRESS.SIZE"="16384") as                                                        
select  a.*
                    ,LAG(ref) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_ref
        ,LAG(endDt) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_endDt
        ,LAG(rowNum) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_rownum
                    ,LAG(ref,2) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_ref_1
        ,LAG(endDt,2) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_endDt_1
        ,LAG(rowNum,2) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_rownum_1
                    ,LAG(ref,3) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_ref_2
        ,LAG(endDt,3) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_endDt_2
        ,LAG(rowNum,3) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_rownum_2
                    ,LAG(ref,4) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_ref_3
        ,LAG(endDt,4) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_endDt_3
        ,LAG(rowNum,4) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_rownum_3
                    ,LAG(ref,5) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_ref_4
        ,LAG(endDt,5) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_endDt_4
        ,LAG(rowNum,5) OVER (PARTITION BY asset ORDER BY asset, endDt, startDt) AS prev_rownum_4
from temp_user.BigDataSet a;
```

I can then compare the prev refs and prev end dates to the current ref and current start date.

Is there are better way to get the previous records, rather than multiple LAGs?

Would it be better to join the big dataset to itself using the asset and ref and where the end date = (start date -1)? How would I then assign the key?

thanks
D

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make this work with a single lag and have it work for any number of previous records.

I wrote this many years ago for Oracle:

https://betteratoracle.com/posts/35-collapsing-continuous-ranges-into-single-rows

Which largely does what you want. The below query would give an idea, but I don't have Hive around to test it out.

```
select t.*,
       max(t.grp) over (order by asset, ref, start asc)
from 
(
select a.*,
       case
         when start - lag(end) over (partition by asset, ref order by start asc) < 1 then
          null
        else
          rownumber // this is an oracle function - maybe Hive has something similar?
        end grp
from table
order by asset, ref, start
) t
```